# How do you add friends in Alpha Sapphire?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

My son has Alpha Sapphire for the 3DS and is unable to add friends. They show up as acquaintances but when the prompt to add them as friends shows, the option to add them is greyed out. I have never played this game, so I have no idea what the problem could be. I googled, but couldn't find anything that tells me how to resolve this issue. Is it a setting that needs to be changed, or is there something that he needs to do, but isn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Player_Search_System):

> The main window of the PSS divides other players in three categories: Friends, Acquaintances, and Passersby. A Passerby will automatically become an Acquaintance if a Battle or Trade (including Wonder Trades ) is made with him/her: **after trading or battling with a player already in the Acquaintances, a prompt to add them to the Friends group will appear**.

Another way to add friends outside the game is from the *Friend List* in the 3DS main menu, you just need a friend code.

Comment: Let me see if he can get this to work. He claims that when prompted to add a friend, only the cancel button is active. I haven't seen this firsthand. If it works, I'll accept. Thanks.